# Why is printwriter not printing the data to file?

Tags: java, printwriter

I am making a program which keeps a tab on when the exe file is opened and closed. It was working fine until God knows what happened and it stopped working. I think it has something to do with the Printwriter close command but I'm not sure.
It is only printing the date not the timings, durations etc.
P.S: I'm not exactly an expert in Java and this is a program made for fun. Please excuse the bad variable names, confusing code etc.
Help is much appreciated! :)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Test {
 static boolean on, off, date = false;
 static int count = 0, counte = 0, opens = 0, closes = 0, temp = 0,
         played = 0;
 static File file;
 static FileWriter fw;
 static PrintWriter pw;
 static ZonedDateTime noww, nowww;
 static Duration duration = null;

 public static void time() throws IOException {
     try {
         pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Oceans.txt", true)));
         if (!date) {
             ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
             DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
             String formattedString = now.format(formatter);
             String datee = formattedString;
             pw.println("-----------------------------------------------DATE: " + datee
                     + "-----------------------------------------------");
          

             date = true;
         }
         if (on) {
             if (opens < 1) {
                 ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
                 DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm:ss Z");
                 String formattedString = now.format(formatter);
                 String Start = formattedString;
                 noww = now;
                 pw.println("Start: " + Start);
                 closes = 0;
                 played += 1;
                 opens = 1;

             }
         }
         
         if (off) {
             if (closes < 1) {
                 ZonedDateTime now2 = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
                 DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm:ss Z");
                 String formattedString = now2.format(formatter);
                 String End = formattedString;
                 nowww = now2;
                 pw.println("End: " + End);
                 try {
                     Duration d = Duration.between(noww, nowww);
                     if (temp < 1) {
                         duration = d;
                     }
                     if (temp == 1) {
                         duration = duration.plus(d);
                     }
                     temp = 1;
                     long hours = duration.toHours();
                     int minutes = (int) ((duration.getSeconds() % (60 * 60)) / 60);
                     int seconds = (int) (duration.getSeconds() % 60);
                     pw.println("Total Duration: " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                     System.err.println("Error: " + e);
                 }
                 pw.println("Number of times game played: " + played);
                 pw.println("--------------------------------------------------");
                 opens = 0;
                 closes = 1;
             }

             System.out.println("Bug");
             String line;
             String pidInfo = "";

             Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getenv("windir") + "\\system32\\" + "tasklist.exe");
             BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

             while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                 pidInfo += line;
             }

             input.close();

             if (pidInfo.contains("Windows10Universal.exe")) {
                 on = true;
                 if (count < 1) {
                     System.out.println("Start: " + Instant.now());
                     counte = 0;
                     on = true;
                     off = false;
                     count = 1;

                 }
             }

             if (!pidInfo.contains("Windows10Universal.exe")) {
                 if (on) {
                     off = true;
                     if (counte < 1) {
                         System.out.println("End: " + Instant.now());
                         count = 0;
                         counte = 1;
                     }
                     on = false;

                 }
             }

         }
     } finally {
         pw.close();

     }

 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     System.out.println("Hello!");
     while (true) {
         time();
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. `on` and `off` are both `false`. If you could reduce this to a [mre] (10 lines or less), it would be easier to help you.

Comment: Hey there! I figured it out it was actually due to a misplaced bracket. 
Thanks though!
Appreciate it!!!

Comment: Glad to read! Since the question has not been answered and frankly I don’t think it will be useful to future readers, allow me to suggest that you can delete it. You have got a delete link under the question.